# How do I use an array formula to sum a range of columns?

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to use array formulas in Excel 365.  Here's a very simple situation I'm starting with.  I have an array of values, and I want to get the sum of the values in each row.  In reality, I have 2000 rows, and 600 columns, but to simplify let's say I just have the following:

[image]

I want to put the sums in the 3rd column (just 6, 60, 600) using an array formula.  I know I can just enter a simple formula for one row and copy it down, but I'm interested in seeing how this is done with an array formula so I can just enter a single formula.  What I want to do will get more complicated after that, but I want to start with this.

(I'm an experienced Excel user, but I haven't worked much with array formulas in Excel 365.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BYROW/LAMBDA:

```
=BYROW(C2:E4,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))
```

[image]

Another option is MMULT

```
=MMULT(C2:E4,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C2:E4),,1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very cool.  I don't think I had seen those functions before.  Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Sure:  `=SUM(C2:C4,D2:D4,E2:E4)`

Comment: @Freond see edit for another option.

Comment: =SUM(C2:C4,D2:D4,E2:E4) is the kind of thing I was trying.  But on the sample data it just gives me 666 in one cell.The MMULT formula is interesting, but it seems inefficient.  

I think the trick to array formulas is to enter a range that Excel recognizes as something to be used as an array, not just a simple range.  E.g., SUM(C2:E4) just sums the whole range.

Comment: Yeah, try: `=C2:C4+D2:D4+E2:E4`  But that will be a pain with as many columns as you have.  What is the issue with BYROW?

Comment: No problem with BYROW. Just wondered if there was a simpler way. Looking at it theoretically, I think there needs to be something in the formula that only makes sense when it's interpreted as an array formula.  When I'm just tying to sum rows in an array, there's no extra dimension or info in the formula to do that.  So the BYROWS function does exactly what's needed, telling Excel "treat this as an array formula."  Once I get used to using the BYROWS approach, I think I will like it.